# Lowest common sql provider installed by default on windows

Tags: sql-server, installation, distribution

Can anyone tell me what data providers are installed by default on windows xp and above for accessing sql server, im looking for (and hoping) that there is a common OLEDB provider, or sql native provider that i could use (for performant reasons ODBC is out of the running) The intended provider must be installed by default as a requirement for distrbution is that nothing can be installed. If one such provider exists could you also provide a connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference: [Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) Installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810805.aspx)

- MDAC 2.7 RTM is pre-installed on Windows XP
- MDAC 2.8 SP1 with XP SP2

"SQLOLEDB" is the provider

One hopes you have nothing earlier than XP SP2...

Answer (score 1):

A vanilla install of Windows XP SP3 I did recently has the SQL 2000 OLEDB driver included. I can't speak for earlier service packs.

Connection string [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server#p6).